# Cтилизация тега select при помощи плагина cuSel

Tags: jquery, html, css

Кто-нибудь пользовался плагином [cuSel](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/verstka-form/nice-select-jquery.html) для стилизации тега `select`?
У меня не совсем получается настроить внешний вид селектов.

Картинка, которая используется в качестве бэкграунда, отображается не полностью, хотя её ширина задана в стилях для `cuSel` под мои размеры.
У двух правых селектов ширина получается по содержимому, хотя картинка-бэкграунд для них задана одна и та же + она опять отображается не по всей ширине.
Плюс у всех трех селектов картинка, которая стрелка для разворачивания списка, получается как бы наложена поверх бэкграунда и при щелчке это заметно.

[image]

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы селекторы были одинаковые по заданной ширине, а не по содержимому, достаточно селектам указать ширину вручную:

```
<select style="width:200px"
```

В любом случае все стили можно подправить, к примеру, открыть в хроме веб-инспектор и по-экспериментировать со стилями блоков сгенерированных скриптом вместо селекта, а потом просто внести изменения в соответствующие классы.

Comment: Да, спасибо, прописать ширину помогло, остался непонятный момент с наложением границ